# Array of linked list c++

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

I create an array where each index holds a bunch of linked lists. This is needed to implement a hash table. 
An example of how I use this is:

```
std::list<string> listArray[sizeOfTable];
```

Would this be the correct usage? And how I can show the content of this hash table?

Comment: _"Would this be the correct usage?"_ No. I'd never use c-style arrays of c++ standard container classes. Best bet (if the size is fixed), use a `std::array<std::list<string>,sizeOfTable>`.

Comment: Note too that for `[sizeOfTable]` or `std::array<..., sizeOfTable>`, the `sizeOfTable` value must be a compile time constant (though GCC has a non-Standard extension for variable length arrays) - even if you don't want to *re*size your table, but do need to dynamically *pre*-size it - you'd be better off with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it like that.

To show the content you'd have to write a bit of code yourself, perhaps like this:

```
for (auto& bucket: listArray) {
   for (auto& item: bucket) {
      cout << "item: " << item << endl;
   }
}
```

Of course, I'm presuming you don't want to use `std::unordered_map` (which is a has table) for a good reason.

Comment: Did you mean `unordered_map`?

Comment: The nested for loops are right, but you'd want `auto&` before the identifiers, and it's nice to avoid identifiers like `list` that are also names in the Standard Library - confuses people leading to mistakes.

Comment: True, the code assumes the variables are already defined. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but I believe a better option is to use `std::vector`. A vector is dynamically expanding array and you will be able to handle hash table re-size this way.

As for the second question - to show the hash table content you will have to iterate over the array and for each cell you will have to iterate over the list in the given cell(most of the cells will be empty but that is not a problem).

Comment: Hash tables don't get resized.

Comment: @ams you serious? All reasonable hash table implementations have a max load factor and resize when the load factor is exceeded. A hash table will perform quite poorly if you put too many elements in it

Comment: Why not use something like std::unordered_map instead? ... I'm missing something here.

Comment: @Robinson using an unordered_map is better option but may not be possible due to various reasons. Also this is not directly related to the question being asked

Comment: Ok, basic hash table implementations don't get resized. The OP does not give the impression of somebody building an advanced implementation, and probably doesn't need the confusion.

Comment: @ams even if the table is not resizing I still believe using a vector is better option.

Comment: Possibly, but only for the same reasons `std::array` would be a better option.

Comment: Thank you for your full reply.
But in this case I have no need of changing the size of the hash table.


For show the hash table , Can you provide an example?